# How do i set Session Token Lifetime programmatically in .NET 4

Tags: wif

Able to configure session token lifetime in web.config like below.

```
  <add type="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SessionSecurityTokenHandler, Microsoft.IdentityModel, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35">
    <sessionTokenRequirement lifetime="00:45:00"></sessionTokenRequirement>
  </add>
  </securityTokenHandlers>
```

But I couldn't figured out how to configure through programmatically in .net 4.0. 
I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know how to configure **session** token lifetime but you can

- Set DefaultTokenLifetime of STS configuration
- Implement GetTokenLifetime method of SecurityTokenService class

Answer (score 0):

Brock Allen wrote about a way to do that for .NET 4.5 at:
http://brockallen.com/2013/02/14/configuring-session-token-lifetime-in-wif-with-the-session-authentication-module-sam-and-thinktecture-identitymodel/

Since their library is open source, learning from it and writing a similar method for .NET 4.0 should be doable.